# Handling Old Very Popular Shopping Questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, old-questions, not-constructive

I was looking through some older questions and I came across [Open Source Alternatives to Reflector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2425973/250725) which itself is linked to [Something Better than .NET Reflector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2646707/250725)

I recall coming across the first question in the past when I was very new on the site and the question helped me when I was looking for a replacement for Reflector, but both are clearly not constructive and would have downvoted into oblivion (and probably deleted) if asked today.

Judging by the number of "Favorites" and the amount of upvotes, many have found the question useful so I stopped before hitting the "flag" button.

Should either question be considered for a historical lock?  Or should we just close them (but  not delete)?

Comment: The standard at SO is: "Over time, closed questions that are not useful as signposts to other questions may also be removed, as well as questions which have [no significant activity over a very long period after being asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)", otherwise, if it's a useful signpost or a popular question (despite being old) it would be locked; your historical question requires site specific answers rather than one size fits all, and would be OT for that reason (though not a decade ago).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vote and / or flag to close it. First and foremost, those questions have received more than enough answers. Keeping them open makes no sense, and they could serve as evidence that such questions are appropriate for the site.

Votes on shopping questions tend to mean 'this is interesting' instead of 'this is useful', even though people probably do find some use in the answers. We don't *typically* lock that type of question, but there are some exceptions for when something is heavily linked to from within the site, or has been extremely well maintained over time. But, once locked, maintenance is impossible without moderator help. That's why we normally don't lock them.

Back in the days where it took a considerable amount of community delete votes to remove content that was up-voted so much, moderators used to have to step in and help speed things along. These days, we don't, and we much prefer to just close questions that otherwise won't get enough views for the community to manage doing so on their own. It's then up to the community to keep the question around or not.

Answer (score 5):

We close those these days.

Closed, upvoted questions will not be deleted automatically, so they are essentially locked. The 'historical' lock is only needed if the questions keep being re-opened.

Comment: That's not exactly what the historical lock is for.  The question being reopened is an indicator that it *might* be a candidate for a historical lock, but by no means *the* reason *or even a factor* as to when a historical lock is given.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas: then I stand corrected.

Comment: Let's just say, it puts it on the community's radar, and then we all come to a consensus as to just *how* important and/or useful it is (given all the factors blah blah) and take it from there.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas: Right, that meshes with my understanding; if a post has historically meant a lot to the community, it is worth locking as a historical post. The lock does protect it from being reopened, does it not?

Comment: Yeah, but if a question keeps being re-opened, we may very well delete it, and then it can't be reopened.  The historical lock is not needed because people can't decide on whether or not it should be opened or closed.  There are recent questions where that's happened, but I certainly wouldn't give them historical locks.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that a historical lock is *only* used to prevent re-opening. I more meant that for many such old questions, the historical lock would not apply even if they were somewhat popular; once closed they stick around without such protection.